# Why can't I Iterate over a string that is returned in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

When I iterate through a string in a void function like this it doesn't give me any problem and iterates through the string I input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void iter_string (void){

   char source[30];
   scanf(" %[^\n]s",source );;
   int length = (int)strlen(source); //sizeof(source)=sizeof(char *) = 4 on a 32 bit implementation
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {

      printf("%c\n", source[i]);

   }
   //return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  iter_string();
  return 0;
}
```

However, problems arise when I modify the function to return the input value and store it in a value in the main function. It gives me an error called segmentation fault:11. Why is this?

```
const char* iter_string (void){

   char source[30];
   scanf(" %[^\n]s",source );;
   int length = (int)strlen(source); //sizeof(source)=sizeof(char *) = 4 on a 32 bit implementation
   for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {

      printf("%c\n", source[i]);

   }
   return *source;
}

int main(void)
{
  char author[30];

  strcpy(author,iter_string());
  printf("%s\n",author );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should enable warnings from your compiler, which would have allowed the compiler to warn you that your function `iter_string` is returning an integer (that is, `*source`, which is a single character) when it promises to return a pointer. Using a small integer (such as the character `a`, which has the value 97) as though it were the address of some useful object in memory is not very useful; most of the time the address is invalid, resulting in a segment fault (i.e. an attempt to look up an invalid address).

Comment: And after you fixed that issue, you might find that your compiler also warns you about the resulting issue described in your answer, that you would be returning a pointer to an object whose lifetime was ending.

Comment: @HetalThaker no, that would return a dangling pointer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are returning a reference to a memory that no longer exists once the function finishes executing.

You have to declare it dinamically if you want to return that pointer:

```
char *source = malloc(30);

// Do your processing here...
return source; // No asterisk here
```

Then in main, to do a proper cleaning on the memory allocated inside the function you should free the stuff you malloc'ed:

```
char * temp = iter_string();
strcpy(author, temp);
free(temp);
```

Other alternativa would be to pass author as parameter and alter it inside.